# How to make a bit value a string

Tags: mysql, string, bit

I have a table being created by a for...each statement; its data populated by mysql db. Each column has an if statement. All data is essentially being displayed correctly. In one column,...

```
if(isset($row->Response) && $row->Response != null) $respcpd[] = @$row->Response;
```

... the output is a bit (1, 0), but I need to convert it to a yes, no string.

I figure I need to use a ternary operator, but I can't figure out the syntax. I have tries several ways, both nothing so far works.

Comment: What code snippets using different ternary syntaxes have you tried? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: Lots of them, I am not sure what they all were. But one of them was: if(isset($row->Response) && $row->Response != null) $respcpd[] ? 'yes' : 'no'

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the ternary operator is

```
(condition) ? (if_true) : (if_false)
```

I'm not sure what you have tried, so it is hard to say why it is not working. But there is always another way of doing the same thing:

```
if (condition)
    doSomethingIfTrue;
else
    doSomethingIfFalse;
```

Comment: if(isset($row->Response) && $row->Response != null) $respcpd[] ? 'yes' : 'no'

Comment: shouldn't there be an equal sign and then a condition. like  Var = (isBitSet) ? "yes" : "no".